# Get collection containing a specific object out of a collection

Tags: c#, select, collections, lambda, where-clause

I've to admit that the title is a little bit confusing.

I've got a collection which contains a collection which contains some properties.

Example:

```
public class LocationalLink {
    public Model.Location Location { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Converter.Link.RoomLockerLink> RoomCollection { get; private set; }
}

public class RoomLockerLink {
    public Model.Room Room { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Locker> LockerCollection { get; private set; }
}
```

In my main application I've got a collection of LocationalLink.

Get collection containing a specific object our of a collection
Now I'd like to get those RoomCollections which are containing a specific Room.

I thought this could be something like that:

```
RoomCollection = LocationalLinkList.Where(o => o.RoomCollection.Where(i => i.Room == obj));
```

I know this doesn't work because the second Parameter of the Where-clause has to be a boolean expression. May anyone could give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change 2nd Where method to Any

```
RoomCollection = LocationalLinkList.Where(o => o.RoomCollection.Any(i => i.Room == obj));
```